# create video from images and then stream to users

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, live-streaming

idea is to create a video from images provided by a user and at the same time stream the generated video to other user demanding it.

kindly tell any efficient way to do this and which language out of PHP and C# .net will be suitable.

have looked into ffmpeg to take images and convert to video and save to server and then stream .. kindly tell if this the possibility or any other method for live streaming.

regards

**UPATE**

consider the following scenario as I understand:

get images from server and start combining them to form a video. at the same time, stream the video to the users requesting it.. for new coming clients, stream the previously generated video from the begining and keep on sending the new video which is being generated from images to the previous clients.

kindly tell if this is possible, if so then what can be the approach. Have read something about pipes but am completely new to ffmpeg and streaming in general.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with ffmpeg. Any language that is turing complete is suitable. They are many methods of live streaming including HLS, RTP, RTMP, etc.

If you need more detailed answers. Please ask more detailed questions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. one of the requirement is that video should stay in main memory for other users to view. is this a valid requirement and if so, is it done automatically or requires some code.